# While deserialize not able to extract these values for XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlhttprequest

```
<Notification>
    <Id>04l5h0000002iBuAAI</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:Social_Post__c" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
        <sf:Id>a015h00002LiNpbAAF</sf:Id>
    </sObject>
</Notification>
```

writing code in c# not able to extract a015h00002LiNpbAAF this id getting null here
can anyone help

Classes which im using

```
public class Notification
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id", Namespace = "http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sObject", Namespace = "urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com")]
    public SObject SObject { get; set; }
}

public class SObject
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sObject", Namespace = "sf:urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

}
```

I want to extract that sObjectId from above xml

Comment: `Id` in `Notification` should not have a `Namespace` attribute. And `Id` in `SObject` has the wrong `ElementName`.

Answer (score 0):

To self-answer this: reverse your thinking. Ask the serializer *what it is expecting right now*, but asking it to *serialize* something. If we do:

```cs
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Notification));
ser.Serialize(Console.Out, new Notification {  Id = "abc",
    SObject = new SObject {  Id = "def" } });
```

we see:

```xml
<Notification xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">abc</Id>
  <sObject xmlns="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <sObject xmlns="sf:urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">def</sObject>
  </sObject>
</Notification>
```

We can ignore the two `xmlns:` declarations, but we can see that `Notification.Id` is in the wrong namespace, and `SObject.Id` has the wrong element name (again, we can mostly ignore the difference between aliased vs inline namespacing; note also that `sf:` isn't part of the namespace). So, fix that:

```cs
public class Notification
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sObject")]
    public SObject SObject { get; set; }
}

public class SObject
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can deserialize:

```cs
var xml = """
    <Notification>
        <Id>04l5h0000002iBuAAI</Id>
        <sObject xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
            <sf:Id>a015h00002LiNpbAAF</sf:Id>
        </sObject>
    </Notification>
    """;

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Notification));
var obj = (Notification) ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
Console.WriteLine(obj.Id);
Console.WriteLine(obj.SObject.Id);
```

(I've also removed the undefined `xsi:` usage)

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it will not work as per my expectations.. your code is working but not as per my prespective  xsi:type="sf:Social_Post__c" this should be there

Comment: @PrajwalGunjal you do understand that your XML is invalid, right? `xsi:type` literally doesn't make sense (cannot be parsed) without a `xmlns:xsi` declaration beforehand. But feel free to add it in: it is probably the one shown in my fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Notification", Namespace = "http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound")]
public class Notification
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sObject")]
    public SObject SObject { get; set; }
}  

[XmlInclude(typeof(SObjType))]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sObject", Namespace = "urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com")]
public class SObject
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id", Namespace = "urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}



[XmlType(TypeName = "Social_Post__c", Namespace = "urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com")]
public class SObjType : SObject
{

}
```

This will give you what you want but your use of xsi is kinda off to me. Id very much like to know more Details.